# PDFKit memory issues ios12

Tags: memory-management, swift4, pdfkit

Edited this question to use a simpler version of the code.
The TestPDF is all text and about 300 pages. As the loop runs it crashes after consuming 2gb of memory. I don’t need the value in the print statement after it’s printed. However the code keeps it in memory. How to clear the memory allocation of the contents  of the print statement before the loop closes?

```
func loadPDFDocument(){
        let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestPDF", withExtension: "pdf")!

        if let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL) {

            for page in 1...document.pageCount {
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                print(document.page(at: page)!.string!)
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Solutions I have tried include `autoreleasepool` and  creating a new PDFDocument object in for each loop and using that. That second option does free the memory but is seriously too slow.

```
 func loadPDFDocument(){
        let documentURL   = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestPDF", withExtension: "pdf")!

     if let document      = PDFDocument(url: documentURL) {



            for page in 1...document.pageCount {
                 DispatchQueue.global().async {
                  let innerDocument = PDFDocument(url: documentURL)!
                     print(innerDocument.page(at: page)!.string!)
                    }
              }

            }

        }
```

Comment: did you solve this???

Comment: @JimBak no. I also had no response on the Apple dev forum. I have moved in to working on other areas of my application. When I revisit this issue before submitting I will most likely use one of my code supports of my developer membership

Comment: Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Have you used Instruments to see what the problem really is?

Answer (score 5):

my solution so far has been to reload the PDFDocument in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`

so I have a global variable

```
 var document =  PDFDocument()
```

use it

```
let pdfURL   = ...
     document =   PDFDocument(url: pdfURL)!
```

then if low memory

```
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    let pdfURL   = ...
        document =  PDFDocument(url: pdfURL)! 
}
```

Comment: my issue was in a big PDF, as long as user scrolls causing pages to load - memory increases. my solution was similar to yours, catch memory warning and reload PDF, make sure to jump to the page last seen by the user.
The idea came to me while trying to understand what Apple did to overcome this, so I opened the PDF in safari and started to scroll. I saw how they reloaded the PDF so I just did the same.
I wonder why it's not getting fixed for so much time!